# Missing parenthesis in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello so i was coding a procedure for my database but i got stuck when i the compiler(*Oracle SQL Developer*) started telling me that

> there is a missing right parenthesis

but there is no missing parenthesis as much as I observe.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generer_listes_preferees (
  p_id_user IN UTILISATEUR."id_user"%TYPE,
  p_films OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  -- Déclarer les variables locales
  CURSOR c_films IS
    SELECT *
    FROM OBJET
    WHERE "categorie_obj" LIKE 'Films' AND "id_objet" IN (
      SELECT "id_objet"
      FROM AVIS
      WHERE "id_user" = p_id_user
      ORDER BY "note" DESC, "date_avis" DESC
    )
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
BEGIN
  -- Générer la liste de films préférés
  OPEN p_films FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(c_films);
END;
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Just move the expression `ORDER BY "note" DESC, "date_avis" DESC` to the place after closing bracket, before `FETCH...`.

Comment: Usually, an Oracle messge tells you the line where to look for the syntax error. And SQL Developer, too, tries to highlight syntax errors.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is not the compiler. It has simply sent the code to the database server for compilation and returned the status and error message to you. "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" is a database error message not an editor message.

Comment: Also, the error message is highlighting a SQL syntax error which would occur with or without the surrounding PL/SQL code. To debug it, you might test the SQL on its own before adding it to the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure does not compile because the query is not valid. In particular, Oracle is looking for the closing parenthesis to finish the subquery, but it finds an unexpected `ORDER BY` clause instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM OBJET
WHERE "categorie_obj" LIKE 'Films' AND "id_objet" IN (
  SELECT "id_objet"
  FROM AVIS
  WHERE "id_user" = p_id_user
  ORDER BY "note" DESC, "date_avis" DESC
)
```

([Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kfgKSwc-))

The error message could indeed be more useful, but the problem with incorrect code is that the parser can't really figure out your intentions.

Even if the `ORDER BY` clause was allowed, it wouldn't accomplish anything. The `IN ()` operator is not sensitive to order. I guess you meant to order the main outer query.

It's also worth noting that `"categorie_obj" LIKE 'Films'` is the same as `"categorie_obj" = 'Films'`. Performance overhead (it has to parse the expression looking for wildcards) is for sure negligible, but I think it's more readable to just be explicit.

*On a side note, I'd advise against double quoting identifiers. The only feature it provides is to hard-code the table/column case, so you're forced to type the quotes and the exact case every time since expressions `WHERE categorie_obj` or `WHERE CATEGORIE_OBJ` will no longer work.*